# Javascript for loop finding before, equal, between and after values?

Tags: javascript

I feel I'm missing something obvious. This is a simple example to illustrate my problem.

I expect current = 3 to return 'before'. current = 4 should return 'key-two, current = 5 should return 'between', current = 7 should return 'key-two' current = 8 should return 'after'.

This code doesn't work as expected. Setting current to 7 returns 'key-two', setting it to 8 or larger returns 'after' setting it to any other number returns between.

```js
let items = []
items['key-one'] = 4
items['key-two'] = 7

let current = 3

let results = ''

for(let key in items) {
    let keyOne = ''
    let keyTwo = ''
    if (key === 'key-one') {
        keyOne = items[key]
    }
    if (key === 'key-two') {
        keyTwo = items[key]
    }
    if (current < keyOne) {
        results = 'before'
    }
    else if (current === items[key]) {
        results = key
    }
    else if (current > keyOne && current < keyTwo) {
        results = 'between'
    }
    else if (current > keyTwo) {
        results = 'after'
    }
}
document.write(results)
```

Comment: You should set `keyOne` and `keyTwo` to some default number, as it is you will end up comparing an empty string to a number which is not going to give you the desired result.

Comment: keyone and keytwo will never both be defined at the saem time because you're using let

Comment: why not use the keys directly? what the serialö approach to set variables (which not work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are effectively creating a new variable each time the loop is iterated. Put `keyOne` and `keyTwo` outside the loop.

```js
let items = []
items['key-one'] = 4
items['key-two'] = 7

let current = 3

let results = ''
let keyOne = ''
let keyTwo = ''
    
for(let key in items) {

    if (key === 'key-one') {
        keyOne = items[key]
    }
    if (key === 'key-two') {
        keyTwo = items[key]
    }
    if (current < keyOne) {
        results = 'before'
    }
    else if (current === items[key]) {
        results = key
    }
    else if (current > keyOne && current < keyTwo) {
        results = 'between'
    }
    else if (current > keyTwo) {
        results = 'after'
    }
}
document.write(results)
```

That's enough to get your existing code workign, but there's a lot that could be improved. Consider this method..

```js
function positionInRange(point, low, high){
  return point > high ? "after" :
    point < low ? "before" :
    point > low && point < high ? "between" :
    point == low ? "key-1" : "key-2"
}

var items = {
  "key-1": 4,
  "key-2": 7
}

var results = positionInRange(3, items['key-1'], items['key-2']);
document.write(results)
```

Comment: I noticed in your improved function you converted the array syntax I was using for items to objects. Are arrays and objects actually the same in javascript?

Comment: @KahunaCoder what you have is really an object. it should have been defined with curlies instead of square brackets but since  arrays inherit from objects it works both ways. all arrays are objects but not all objects are arrays. there is no such thing as associative arrays in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You essentially do not need that for loop. Try this code below

```js
let items = {};
items['key-one'] = 4
items['key-two'] = 7

let current = 4

let results = ''
let keyOne = items['key-one'];
let keyTwo = items['key-one'];

if (current < keyOne) {
  results = 'before'
} else if (current === keyOne) {
  results = "key-one";
}else if (current === keyTwo) {
  results = "key-two";
} else if (current > keyOne && current < keyTwo) {
  results = 'between'
} else if (current > keyTwo) {
  results = 'after'
}

document.write(results)
```

Comment: Missed that. Edited.

Comment: I like this solution as well. It opened my eyes to the fact that I didn't need a loop at all. For some reason when I'm dealing with arrays (which apparently I really wasn't since associative arrays are actually objects in JavaScript) I always think I need a loop. My accepted answer pointed out what was wrong with my code logic though, the use of let in a loop. Your answer pointed out I didn't even need a loop at all. Great answer too!